# Hazardous materials handled by amateur chemists

Tags: everyday-chemistry, safety

I'm a enthusiastic and devoted amateur chemist (in disguise, I'm actually a mathematician), but lately I've been thinking to what extend it is safe to pursue my hobby. I'm after all an amateur with just high-school lab skills and some unnecessary math to back me up. I really love chemical experiments, but I don't want to get seriously injured. The point is that same very basic materials, like sulfuric acid or cyclohexylamine, already have a 3 on [the NFPA 704 scale of health hazards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NFPA_704#Blue), quoting:

> Short exposure could cause serious temporary or moderate residual injury (e.g. chlorine)

Of course I read the MSDS of the chemicals I'm working with, wear a protective lab coat and tightly connected safety goggles, plus safety gloves, but I don't have nearly the safety equipment of a normal lab (fumehood, eye showers, sprinklers, etc.) To to concretize my question:

- Speaking for all amateur chemists out there: to what extend do you as a professional chemist consider amateurs like me to be safe. Can we handle level 3 or perhaps even level 4 chemicals, or should we stick with 2 (greatly reducing our potential experimenting terrain)?
- What measure can we (and should we) take to ensure our safety?

I understand that the capabilities vary greatly between people, but there was not sufficient information regarding this topic (from reputable sources) for me to be found on the internet, so I though I post it here. I don't feel like this is a primarily opinion based question, as there is at least to some degree consensus that amateurs cannot (and are not allowed to!) safely handle, say for example [tabun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabun_%28nerve_agent%29) or potassium cyanide (just a ridiculous example to illustrate my point).

I hope you can appreciate my concerns and that if this is not the right place for this type of question (I think it is, there is even a safety tag here) you cordially redirect me to an other more suited place and close this.

Comment: `to what extend do you as a professional chemist consider amateurs like me to be safe.` That's a pretty good indicator that at least a part of this is opinion-based.  However, I think there are some good questions buried in here (it's honestly too broad at present as well).  I would split this up into a series of *very specific* questions about lab safety, not just a blanket question.

Comment: As an aside, please *do* seek advice from someone that has used some of these chemicals before (not just random folks on the internet) if you are unsure.  This can be an exciting hobby, but is a lot less enjoyable when missing appendages or organs.

Comment: It may further be helpful if you specify the quantities you're dealing with and give a more exact account of which chemicals you're interested in. The hazards of macroscale experiments are often distinct from microscale ones, and there are too many disparate classes of chemicals to give useful advice beyond the most obvious of generalizations.

Comment: To give a concrete example of why more details are needed: you note that you wear safety gloves, but you haven't specified the material. If you're dealing with strong acids, for example, then common materials like latex and nitrile rubber will likely be unsuitable at all but low concentrations. If you use, e.g., ethyl acetate as a solvent, latex should be fine, while nitrile will dissolve. Probably only gloves with laminate film are resistant to most common chemicals across the board, but then you have to sacrifice manual dexterity.

Comment: @jonsca, Of course there is some opinion in this question, but I don't think it is primarily opinion based. Splitting could indeed be an option, let me think about it how this could be split in the most efficient and clear way _"As an aside, please do seek advice from someone that has used some of these chemicals before"_ whenever I can I do that, but this is not always possible.

Comment: @GregE. In the case of sulfuric acid and cyclohexylamine (just two random example) I'm talking about handling at most something under a liter (this can really range from 5ml to 1L). In fact I don't think, I even reach that except for solvents like acetone, ethanol, toluene, etc. When I say, I wear safety gloves I mean those that are (as far to my knowledge) most suited for the chemicals being used, not any specific. This could probably be a good split question: what gloves should be worn under which circumstances (when working with acid or bases or some organic compound) (to be continued...)

Comment: as far as this can be generalized (perhaps including some reference material where the amateur chemist can deduce for himself what gloves are best suited for the occasion).

Comment: @Jori, yes, I definitely concur that splitting this into separate questions of narrower scope would be preferable. That would permit you to provide more specifics and elicit more useful responses.

Comment: @GregE. Also, this question was more about to which extend amateur chemist can generally work with chemicals (like level 3 as indicated by NFPA 704 or some other well expected scale). The dangers of the specific chemicals can be learned from MSDS's. Thanks for all your input, I'll try to narrow down as best as is possible and favorable.

Comment: @Jori, fair enough, but that's a question that's both broad and subjective. I don't personally see a way to answer that which is both definitive and goes beyond generic advice/platitudes. That may be a failure on my part, however.

Comment: @Jori I don't know the legalities of where you are located, but in general, handling hazardous materials requires a license, so it's not necessarily a matter of "can work with" as "are permitted to work with".  Anyway, we've given you plenty of food for thought here, so I look forward to your edited question.

Comment: @jonsca, Yes, plenty food for thought haha. I'm located in the Netherlands. Yes we have laws here regarding chemicals (of course), but most of them are to stop people from making illicit drugs. As far as I can oversee it, it seems that most level 3 chemicals can be obtained, but most level 4 chemicals not (potassium cyanide requires registration here for example). It will cost me some time to split this, so that it will be useful to my as well as useful to a more broad (amateur) public.

Comment: Ahem. If you have place, you can buy or assemble improvised fume hood. As for storage, I'd say that anything stable below 100 C and having bp above 50 C is safe to store, if obvious safety rules are followed (do not store things with low bp open, do not store oxidizers and reducers together, keep reducers and solvents in dedicated metal cases.) With lack of fume hood anything with heavy gas production is probably out of question as most organic solvents and reagents with bp below 100-150. Other than that, just do an exhaustive research and you should be fine. But learn to perfrorm first aid.

Comment: However, for obvious reason, I'd avoid anything with toxic dose below ~ 1 g aeven having access to all required equipment just as anything involving high explosives and most explosive mixtures. Also, many things in a lab will put a skunk to a shame, and that is another reason to be picky. anything that can produce toxic vapors is a strict no-no without a fume hood or at least open air lab.

Comment: @permeakra You mean a LD50 below 1g? Or just hazardous dose? Even ammonia is hazardous when ingesting >1g (according to Wikipedia this could kill you quite easily, but this could be an error from their side as it seems a bit extreme). All potential hazardous chemicals I'm working with are bp > 100 °C (lowest I use is 112.0 °C, keeping reaction refluxed at about 100 °C). I now a fumehood can be easily constructed, but I lack the space to place the tubing (I could hang it out a window simply, but then the neighbors will think I'm running a hemp plantation).

Comment: However, there is a small ventilating system in place (I'm using an unused bathroom) and I could open the window and adding an extra ventilator ([something like this](http://renovari-amenajari.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/ventilator.jpg)). Of course I do my research on the chemicals I'm using, but it is sometimes hard for an amateur to judge them (e.g. I can easily judge that reactions that produce phosgene are not in my league, especially without fumehood, but inspecting if something like toluene or nitroethane is safe for me is much more diffecult). I appreciate your help :-)

Comment: Ammonia is relatively safe as it stinks like hell, it is almost impossible to ingest significant amount of it. However, by 'toxic dose' I mean the minimum dose to give risks of permanent or severe injury (not even death). The problem is that working on large scale it is surprisingly easy to get a small dose. Some toxins can accumulate (most notably been organic mercury compounds), so they are ok to work once or twice but a thing to avoid for long use. I understand your concerns about PR, but if you work with anything producing toxic vapours or dust, you have to install fume hood anyway.

Comment: For compounds there are two risks other then immidiate toxity: explosive hazard and cancer risk. The first is always noted, the second is not so easy to measure as it accumulates. For example, it is generally assumed that all aromatics is potentially carcinogenic, especially polycondensed, but alkyl derivatives are less dangerous (so, toluene instead of benzene). Flammability is something to live with, unfortunately.

Comment: For reactions the main risks are dangerous by-product/intermediate compound (usually mentioned) or risk of autospeeding reaction, that can run out of control (usually also mentioned). Because of it it is highly recommended to make several tests on small scale before going large scale and make an effort to keep temperature from rising too high for exothermic reactions (keep an ice bath nearby, use low-boiling solvents etc).